# wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) Rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an error for this method below

```
 def mymethod
    cat = Cat.find_by_cat_id_and_animal_id_and_name(catid, haustierid, cat_name)
    if cat.name.nil?
       if cat.name == "beauty"
           #doworkhere
        end
      end
 end
```

The thing is that, I have a cat table, with a column of name. Where inside the cat name, there are different rows containing the name ("beauty", "ugly", etc.). I tried to basically loop in the cat table, going into the rows and check if "beauty" is there, then do something. However, it returns that I am entering wrong arguments. I can not understand about the wrong arguments , is this the correct way of going in a loop inside the "cat name column" 
Thank you for any answer.

Comment: you wrote "if cat.name.nil?", but after you also wrote cat.name == 'beauty'. "if cat.name == 'beauty'". I think this if sentence is never run because cat.name is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code but no one can explain the error message you receive.
You probably need to post the code inside the `if`.

In the meanwhile, let me show a few issues

```
cat = Cat.find_by_cat_id_and_animal_id_and_name(catid, haustierid, cat_name)
```

You probably mean

```
cat = Cat.find_by_id_and_animal_id_and_name(catid, haustierid, cat_name)
```

Also, you might want to use scopes (or named scopes if you use Rails 2)

```
if cat.name.nil?
   if cat.name == "beauty"
       #doworkhere
```

I won't ever enter the second `if`. A name cannot be nil and a String at the same time.
Also, assuming you wanted to say !nil? you can write it in a more concise way by doing

```
if !cat.name.nil? && cat.name == "beauty"
    #doworkhere
```

or simply

```
if cat.name == "beauty"
    #doworkhere
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your find query should be:

```
cat = Cat.find_by_id_and_animal_id_and_name(catid, haustierid, cat_name)
```

and not

```
cat = Cat.find_by_cat_id_and_animal_id_and_name(catid, haustierid, cat_name)
```

Thanks....